# How to read a text file on Xamarin Forms PCL project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to read a text file (Embedded resource) on my Xamarin.Forms PCL project.
On the [working with files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) xamarin docs it suggests this code:

```
var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

The problem is that I can't find what this LoadResourceText is. All I found is that it's a type in my Assembly. But I can't really understand what it means.

And I can't find anywhere a clear practical explanation of what I need to do.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: https://components.xamarin.com/view/pclstorage

Comment: PCL storage doesn't work for existing embedded resource files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To read an existing file you need to replace `LoadResourceText` with a class that you have in your PCL project. It is used to get the assembly that contains the embedded file. You will also need to replace `WorkingWithFiles` with the namespace of your PCL project.

You need to add `using System.Reflection;` for the code to compile.

If you want to create a file at runtime and read it later you can use [PCLStorage Library](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) like this:

```
public async Task PCLStorageSample()
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("answer.txt",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync("42");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to load an existing embedded resource file. If I change LoadResourceText with any class in my project it complains that "Type does not contain a definition for GetTypeInfo(). I'm looking at the sample project from the docs and LoadResourceText doesn't implement it too. It's just a normal ContentPage. Any idea?

Comment: @Dpedrinha: Do you have this code in the PCL project?

Comment: Yes, inside portable project.

Comment: @Dpedrinha: Add using System.Reflection;

Comment: There you go! Thanks! How did you find that out?

Comment: @Dpedrinha: VS 2015 suggests missing using statements :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109591/discussion-between-dpedrinha-and-giorgi).