# How to access Embedded Resource from PCL Targeting ASP.NET CORE & .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: dll, asp.net-core, embedded-resource, portable-class-library, .net-4.6

I have a PCL Targeting ASP.NET CORE & .NET Framework 4.6.

In the root of PCL, I have added PCLResource.txt and marked it as Build Action > Embedded Resource.

Publish to NuGet, Installed from NuGet to my Consumer WinForm App (4.6.2)

Calling `PCL.TestMethod()` works. However,

```
string[] asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

And

```
var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

results in :

- PCLConsumerApp.Form1.resources
- PCLConsumerApp.Properties.Resources.resources

And

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("PCL.PCLResrouce.txt"));
```

results in `null`

Using dotPeek, I can see PCLResrouce.txt in the DLL.
[image: dotPeek of PCL Resources]

**How do I get access to the Embedded Resource text file as a consumer?**

I have used the following resources:

- [Tip: Accessing Binary Resources in Portable Class Library](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2014/08/10/tip-accessing-binary-resources-in-portable-class-library/)
- [How to read a text file on Xamarin Forms PCL project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725802/how-to-read-a-text-file-on-xamarin-forms-pcl-project)
- [How to read a resource file within a Portable Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963781/how-to-read-a-resource-file-within-a-portable-class-library)

And I realize I mispelled resource :/ but thats not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was I was not getting the PCL Assembly.

Solution:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StaticPCLClass));
```

I am not necessarily working with this class when I need the resource, but this allows me to get the Assembly.
Now I am able to call:

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("PCL.PCLResrouce.txt"));
```

Used help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041000/loop-through-all-the-resources-in-a-resx-file#answer-2041057).